# ASP.NET MVC and Angular 4 mini SPA - Footer issue

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, angular

**Application Background**: My application is built up using ASP .net MVC (.net framework 4.6) and several Angular 4 mini SPAs

Mini SPA is loaded from one of the view, say `Subscription.cshtml`. Please note my comments in code below:

```
@section styles{
    <link href="~/apps/userSubscription/styles.e8e9c3a3817e92de1e39.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
}
@*This is mini SPA*@
<sb-subcription-app-root>
    @*This is loader to show while mini SPA is bootstrapped*@
    <div class="loading-icon">
        <div class="text-center">
            <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-fw" style="font-size:55px;"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</sb-subcription-app-root>

@section scripts{
    <script src="~/apps/userSubscription/inline.4306fb1489008775a724.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="~/apps/userSubscription/polyfills.b92561b85131ad96e15f.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="~/apps/userSubscription/vendor.d7d84c623190e8bb1494.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="~/apps/userSubscription/main.c9d275f7937435642d76.bundle.js"></script>
}
```

**Issue**: Footer is pushed to top. My footer is in `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
<footer class="footer">
    <div class="top-footer">
        <div class="container">
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

**Problem description**:

1. When view `Subscription.cshtml` is being loaded. UI appears as shown in picture below. I believe at this point of time my angular app is getting bootstrapped
   [image]
2. After angular app is bootstrapped, loader disappears (which I think is correct) and then **footer is pushed to top** for 2-3 sec until DOM is loaded as shown in picture

[image]

**What I need:** I would like to hide footer until DOM (which includes angular mini SPA) is loaded. Any CSS and JS solution would work for me.

Comment: Any suggestion/help guys?

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround you may try following approach.

1) Hide footer by default:

```
<footer class="footer hide" id="footer">
```

2) Mark the element that must be rendered before the footer could be shown:

```
<div id="bootstraper">
```

3) Run javascript polling process to switch footer visibility:

```
(function() {
  var timer = setInterval(function() {    
     if(document.getElementById('bootstraper')) {
       clearInterval(timer);
       document.getElementById('footer').classList.remove("hide");
     }
  }, 40);
})();
```

As you see, we just show the footer after some (needed) element has been rendered and become accessible via `document`. This solution is a bit hacky and I would recommend you to look for a way that would be more specific to your situation, to your environment. This would require more deep research:

- who loads that DOM which is 2-3 sec late?
- if it's the Angular App responsibility, then the App must handle this process;
- and this process may not be just a primitive polling, for example the delaying entity may itself tell that it is done...
- maybe [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event would be enough? (just show the footer when it's fired)